# Nautilus 2.16 - trash confirmation difference between filesystems

Tags: filesystems, redhat, nautilus, recycle-bin, gconf

Apologies if this question seems rather trivial, but it's causing me some frustration.

I have a Redhat 5.3 installation, using nautilus-2.16.2-7.el5 that has two filesystems mounted. Under user1, when sending to the trash (pressing Del) on filesystem A we receive a confirmation dialogue box (do you want to etc). The behaviour is the same on filesystem B.

However, under user2, we receive the confirmation on Del on filesystem A, but **NOT** on filesystem B.

I've tried renaming the ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus folder and logging out/in to reset the Nautilus settings, but it's still behaving the same.

This is basically leading to users accidently deleting data, which isn't great!

Any advice would be appreciated folks!

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that creating a new user profile and copying the settings corrected the problem (even though there was nothing filesystem specific in the gconf file).

cp /home/new_username/.gconf/apps/nautilus/preferences/%gconf.xml /home/username/.gconf/apps/nautilus/preferences/